# Toposes in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, topos-theory

I know the definition of topos and read an introduction to algebraic geometry.

I heard that topos is used for algebraic geometry and want to know detail.

Where can I read about this?

Comment: Probably one of the first and best reference is SGA 4 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9minaire_de_G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_Alg%C3%A9brique_du_Bois_Marie

Comment: On the other hand if you learned about topos from the logic point of view (elementary topos, as categories with object classifiers and so on), this may not help you a lot in algebraic geometry, since all topos that come up are directly seen as sheaves categories on grothendieck sites.

Comment: @Captain Lama: I agree that all relevant toposes in algebraic geometry are Grothendieck toposes. However, that doesn't preclude you from doing interesting logical stuff with them! For instance, one can use [modal operators for talking about spreading of properties from points to neighbourhoods](http://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/notes.pdf).

Comment: @user53216: A main motivation was the development of étale cohomology. You can read about it in Wikipedia or [Milne's very nice notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/lec.html).

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt That's completely right. I'm just saying that they generally use sort of different languages and point of view in logic and in algebraic geometry, so if you're familiar with one, you may not be at ease with the other (but of course it's fruitful to keep in mind and use the dictionary).